# Is there a direct method of identifying the index of the convex hull points in the original set of points in shapely?

Tags: python, indexing, convex-hull

I have a set of points. The shapely convex_hull method gives me the points that make up the exterior of the convex hull, no problem. I know I could take these points and compare them to the original set of points, and then determine which index they are in the original set of points, but this has yielded errors in the past, and I believe it's slow as well. So, is there any way to identify the index of the convex hull points in the original set of points instead of pulling them out of the original set?

What my code currently does:

```py
import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry as spgm

points = np.asanyarray([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0.5,0.5]])
points = spgm.MultiPoint(points)
points_ch = points.convex_hull.exterior.coords.xy

In[1]: points_ch
Out[1]: (array('d', [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]), array('d', [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]))
```

What I would like for the output is the indexes of the array.

```py
points_index = points.convex_hull.exterior.index
In[2]: = points_index
Out[2]: = [0,1,2,3]
```

The reason I am seeking the indexes is because I want to use the convex hull points in reference to the surrounding points which are not in the convex hull, in order to approximate local curve tangents/normals. If there is a built-in function for that, it is possible it will work (so it would be helpful to know about it) but at the same time, my original point data is not smooth, and I might have to try different smoothing schemes to get the right slopes. I am open to using other packages for the convex hull identification - I do not need to use shapely for my application.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out scipy has the answer to my question (although if anybody finds out how to do this in shapely, that would be a useful answer, too).

```python
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np

points = np.asanyarray([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0.5,0.5]])
hull = ConvexHull(points)
point_indexes = hull.vertices

In[1]: point_indexes
Out[1]: array([0, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int32)
```

It even orders them for you.